# Read selected Item from List

Tags: development

I have a code that read all items from List Airtports. I want to get selected Item from List. How can i change below code to get it done, Please help

```
function ReadListItem() {

        var listTitle = "Airports";

        //Get the current client context
        context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var airportList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);


        var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

        this.listItems = airportList.getItems(camlQuery);

        context.load(listItems);


        context.executeQueryAsync(ReadListItemSucceeded, CreateListFailed);


    }

    function ReadListItemSucceeded(sender, args) {

        var itemsString = '';
        var enumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {

            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
            itemsString += 'AirportName: ' + listItem.get_item('AirportName') + ' AirportCode: ' + listItem.get_item('AirportCode') + '\n';


        }

        alert(itemsString);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get selected item"? A specific item? This currently loops through all items in the list. Can you be more clear on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a standard list view, you can use `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems` to get the id of the selected list item. Then you can retrieve the whole item (or a part of properties you need):

Here is an example:

```
var listGuid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()
//in this example only first selected item is retrieved
var selectedItemId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()[0].id
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
var list = lists.getById(listGuid);
var item = list.getItemById(selectedItemId);
ctx.load(item);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var title = item.get_item("Title");
    alert(title);
}, function(){alert("error");});
```